# Origin of "clip" in "clip around the ears"

Tags: meaning, etymology

"Clip" commonly refers to a device for holding things together. One dictionary says it's "of unknown origin, first occurring in the 15th century." In such phrases as "giving him a clip around the ear", where does the word come from?

Comment: Also "giving him a clip around the ear": do you mean in the sense of a haircut, or of a bruise?

Comment: @MετάEd: Fairly obviously OP means *a sharp smack about the head*. I don't see he needs to explain that any more clearly - it's a standard idiomatic expression.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe regional then. I've run into *clipping* of course as an (American) football term, and *boxing* someone on the ear, but never that particular phrase that you consider idiomatic. Hence my question.

Comment: @Robert: OED says it's an extension from original Norse *klippa, klippen* - *"to make a sharp sound"* (hence horses go clippety-clop, I suppose). That sense transferred to *clip=cut* from the sound of shears/scissors. It also led to *speed* (you can *move at a fair clip*), and to the "crack" of slapping someone round the head, among other senses.

Comment: @MετάEd: We learn something new every day! ***You've*** just learnt what it means, and ***I've*** just learnt that it's [mainly a British usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clip+round+the+ear&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=). That link is to Google Books British Corpus; if you switch it to American, the prevalence % drops to a tenth of what it was.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought it was just what educated people said instead of "slap upside the head" which is a truly ugly expression.

Answer (score 2):

*Clip* has been used as a noun since 1830 to mean, in the OED’s definition, ‘a smart blow, stroke’. This definition is given under the entry for *clip* with the core sense of a cut, originally in the context of sheep-shearing. It is perhaps a relatively short step from applying an instrument to the covering of an animal’s skin in order to remove it to applying a stick or the hand to the body of a human in order to hurt it.

Answer (score 2):

The OED has *clip* as a colloquial, transitive verb meaning "To hit smartly" since 1855 (this is sense 8 of *clip* v.2):

> 1855   ‘Q. K. P. Doesticks’ *Doesticks, what he Says* xii. 99,   97's engineer clipped one of 73's men with a trumpet.
>
> 1880   T. Q. Couch *Gloss. Words E. Cornwall in Gloss. Cornwall* 90   *Klip*, to strike or cuff. ‘I klipped 'en under the ear.’

Other senses under *clip* v.2 are to cut with scissors or shears (often to make tidy), to cut or snip a part away, to shear sheep, to figuratively cut something short, to cut words short or prounounce imperfectly, or to move wings rapidly.

These meanings aren't too far away from a clean, fast blow.

Etymologically, these senses of *clip* are from Middle English *clipp-en*, and probably from Old Norse *klipp-a*:

> The Old Norse and Low German *klippa* , *klippen* , was probably identical with Low German *klippen* to make a sharp sound, cited under clip v.3, the application being transferred, as in *clack , click , clank , clink , clap* , from the sound to associated sharp actions; [other] senses and [another definition], show that the notion of cutting is not inseparable from the word. There may also have been onomatopoeic influence: in the utterance of clip, as of snip, there is a cut-short effect, which aptly suits the act.

Comment: Why is there a discrepancy between the (OED) dates in @BarrieEngland's answer and yours?

Comment: Mine are for the (later) verb, Barrie's are for the (earlier) noun. [Verbing weirds language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(linguistics))[.](http://aoife.allegracom.ca/images/verbing_sm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [UrbanDictionary Link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clip%20round%20the%20ear)

> A soft but firm strike with the hand delivered to the side of the
>   head, characteristically by a parent to a child. The strike is
>   designed not so much to hurt as to shock the offending minor. In a
>   modern context, some might construe this as child abuse, although it
>   is an accepted method of disciplining children provided restraint is
>   shown.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please review [how to answer questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer), specifically: Provide context for links that you post.

Answer (score 0):

Mediaeval Knights used their horse as get-a-away cars to get to and from the battle...their grooms ,usually young lads, were ordered to maintain these horses at readiness ..if these  were not ready for pursuit or escape as the case may be then the grooms were punished severely by having an ear cut off or "clipped"..hence "a clip around the ear"

Comment: Interesting, ROBAT. Have you any evidence to support your claim?

Comment: Please, a reference! A link, something, anything that might backup this origin.

Comment: Fatal Colours..Towton 1461 by George Goodwin Page 204 2nd para...footnote:Goodman The Wars Of The Roses:The Soldiers Experience p.138

Comment: Whereas, grooms did have their ears cut off, the passage does not indicate the origins of "clip round the ear". From the book - "With that potential purpose in mind, the role of the groom, who might be little more than a child, was extremely important. He was expected to remain on standby at his post. Any desertion was liable to be severely punished, for instance with the loss of an ear.[13] The phrase a clip around the ear denoted a lasting punishment in that period." The final sentence is humour, not an authoritative source.

Comment: From the source, Goodman “The Wars Of The Roses”, that Page quotes in “Fatal Colours..Towton 1461” at [13] above: “Boys and pages, with foot archers, were liable to lose the right ear, if they cried ‘To horseback’ (perhaps precipitating unauthorised withdrawals from the camp or field).They were apparently subject to the general prescriptions in the ordinance.” There is no mention of “A clip round the ear."